# JOIN skipping duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT `Bilder_W2L`.Filnamn, `Bilder_W2L`.MD5_Hash, `BildData_W2L`.Bildkategori
FROM `Bilder_W2L`
INNER JOIN `BildData_W2L` ON `Bilder_W2L`.BildID = `BildData_W2L`.BildID
WHERE `Bilder_W2L`.Status = 0
```

BildData_W2L has 28 rows.
Bilder_W2L has 21 rows.

I just want the row data from BildData_W2L on the 21 rows...
 So rows in BildData_W2L can have duplicate BildID.

It's a issue with the INNER JOIN, so to say. but i'm not sure which one to use or how to change the sql.

Comment: Please be precise of which Database Server you use.

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing with the Query? You haven't told us what the issue is.

Comment: Yes, the issue is that the RESULT is 28 rows, (duplicates) when I only want to return the 21 rows from Bilder_W2L along with the joined data from BildData_W2L.

Comment: If I understand you correctly this is not possible. 2 BildData entries might have the same BildID but a different Bildkategori so which one should it consider?

Comment: I managed to solve it with DISTINCT.

Comment: Which will only work if Bildkategori is the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT `Bilder_W2L`.Filnamn, `Bilder_W2L`.MD5_Hash, `BildData_W2L`.Bildkategori
FROM `Bilder_W2L`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `BildData_W2L` ON `Bilder_W2L`.BildID = `BildData_W2L`.BildID
WHERE `Bilder_W2L`.Status = 0
```

Is this what are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` if you allow multiple selections on the second table to have the same value as the first table. I think that's what you're looking for.